# property not updating passed to modal componentProps

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using modal in Ionic and I am passing componentProps:

```js
        //in the Main component
        someList:number[] = [1, 2];
        someString:string = "test";

        async presentModal(ev: any) {
               const modal = await this.modalController.create({
               component: ModalComponent,
               componentProps: {
                      someList: this.someList,
                      someString: this.someString
                 }
              });
             await modal.present(); 
         }
```

The modal component ModalComponent itself defines

```js
        @Input('someList') someList;
        @Input('someString') someString;
```

When I update in the ModalComponent:

```js
        this.someList.push(3);
```

...it reflects the change in the the Main component/template. but if I update

```js
       this.someString = "new string";
```

...it does not reflect in the main component/template.

Not exactly sure why, any way around this?

NOTE: I can get around this by passing "this" to componentProps:

```js
          componentProps: {
                  ref: this
          }
```

...and then accessing the "someString" property from "ref" (ie: ref.someString), and it will reflect in the Main component/template when changed in the ModalComponent. But I feel that passing a reference to the entire component is not good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass back the changes to your main component after the modal dismiss like this:

```
dismiss() {
    this.modalController.dismiss({
      someString: this.someString,
    });
}
```

and in your parent component add this after the init of the modal:

```
modal.onDidDismiss().then(data => {
  this.someString= data.data.someString;
});
```

so it will look for you like this:

```
    async presentModal(ev: any) {
           const modal = await this.modalController.create({
           component: ModalComponent,
           componentProps: {
                  someList: this.someList,
                  someString: this.someString
             }
          });
         modal.onDidDismiss().then(data => {
           this.someString= data.data.someString;
         });
         await modal.present(); 
     }
```